# getting for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) in this code

Tags: ruby

I am doing the beginning ruby book and this is what I have for my code, which gives the following error:

`in 'show_current_description': undefined method 'full_description' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`

The code is as follows. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
class Dungeon
  attr_accessor :player

  def initialize(player_name,start_location)
    @player=Player.new(player_name,start_location)
    puts @player.location
    @rooms=[]
    show_current_description
  end

  def show_current_description
    @rm=find_room_in_dungeon(@player.location)
    @rm.full_description
  end

  def find_room_in_dungeon(reference)
    @rooms.detect{|room| room.reference == reference; puts room.full_description}
  end
  def add_room(reference,name,description,connections)
    @rooms << Room.new(reference,name,description,connections)
  end

  Player=Struct.new(:name,:location)

  class Room 
    attr_accessor :reference, :name, :description, :connections

    def initialize(reference,name,description,connections)
      @reference=reference
      @name=name
      @description=description
      @connections=connections
    end

    def full_description
      "You are in " + @description
    end
  end
end

d=Dungeon.new("Good Man",:small_cave)
d.add_room(:small_cave,"Small Cave","This is a small claustrophobic cave", {:east => :largecave})
d.add_room(:large_cave,"Large Cave","This is a large cavernous cave", {:west => :smallcave})

puts d.player.name
d.show_current_description
```

Comment: Sorry, just realized my stupidity. Was following example after example, and did not realize that I was calling show_current_description in the initialize as well. Thats where the error was coming from.

Thanks for all the help everybody! as always i learned a lot because of this though. lot of googling...

Comment: Closing this as too localized based on your last answer (which I converted to a comment).

Answer (score 6):

The error that you posted means that this line...

```
@rm.full_description
```

...is trying to call `full_description` on an object that has no such method, because the `@rm` object is `nil`. From that we can deduce that the previous line...

```
@rm=find_room_in_dungeon(@player.location)
```

...set `@rm` to `nil` as the result of the `find_room_in_dungeon` method. If we look at that method...

```
@rooms.detect{|room| room.reference == reference; puts room.full_description}
```

...we see one problem. The `detect` method uses the return value of the block to figure out if a room should be used or not. However, the `puts` method (which is the last in the block, and hence the return value of the block) always returns `nil`. Hence, `@rooms.detect` will never find anything. So let's fix that by removing the `puts` altogether:

```
@rooms.detect{|room| room.reference == reference }
```

That should help, but it didn't solve the problem. We're still getting `nil` from this method. Let's look deeper.

First, let's validate our assumptions about what the precondition for this method is. Before that changed line, we add `p @rooms, reference` to the `find_room_in_dungeon` method. Running the code now, we see this output:

```
[]
:small_cave
```

Ah-ha! So that's the problem. We're looking for the `small_cave` room, but our list of rooms is empty! We know that we're calling `d.add_room` at the bottom of the script...why isn't it working?

Let's see where we are when this code breaks. Here's the full backtrace from the error message:

```
C:/tmp.rb:13:in `show_current_description': undefined method `full_description' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from C:/Users/gkistner.NVIDIA.COM/Desktop/tmp.rb:8:in `initialize'
from C:/Users/gkistner.NVIDIA.COM/Desktop/tmp.rb:43:in `new'
from C:/Users/gkistner.NVIDIA.COM/Desktop/tmp.rb:43:in `<main>'
```

Ah-HA! The problem is that we call `show_current_description` as part of our `initialize` method, before we've had a chance to add rooms to the dungeon.

Here are some ways we could fix this:

1. Change the Dungeon constructor to accept a list of rooms as part of initialization, so we can do this all at once. Here are three different ways one could do it:

   ```
   # Method number one, accept an array of rooms
   class Dungeon
     def initialize(name,start,rooms=[])
       @player = ...
       @rooms  = rooms
       yield(self) if block_given?
       show_current_description
     end
   end

   d = Dungeon.new( "Bob", :small_cave, [
     Dungeon::Room.new(...),
     Dungeon::Room.new(...)
   ] )


   # Method 2: Allow an initializer block
   class Dungeon
     def initialize(name,start)
       @player = ...
       @rooms  = []
       yield(self) if block_given?
       show_current_description
     end
   end

   d = Dungeon.new( "Bob", :small_cave ) do |dungeon|
     dungeon.add_room(...)
     dungeon.add_room(...)
   end


   # Method 3 (experts only!): Initialize block runs in scope
   class Dungeon
     def initialize(name,start,&initializer)
       @player = ...
       @rooms  = []
       instance_eval(&initializer) if initializer
       show_current_description
     end
   end

   d = Dungeon.new( "Bob", :small_cave ) do
     add_room(...)
     add_room(...)
   end
   ```
2. Don't show the current description as part of the initializer. Just remove that line, and when running show the description when construction is complete:

   ```
   d = Dungeon.new(...)
   d.add_room(...)
   d.add_room(...)
   d.show_current_description
   ```
3. Make your `show_current_description` method more robust, so that it can handle the `nil` case:

   ```
   def show_current_description
     @rm = find_room_in_dungeon(@player.location)
     puts @rm.full_description if @rm
   end
   ```

You could choose to do 1 or 2, but I'd suggest also doing 3.

Answer (score 1):

The 4th line from the bottom, `@rooms  :largecave})`, is a syntax error. The real code surely looks different.

Anyway, "undefined method full_description for nil:NilClass" means that @rm, returned by `find_room_in_dungeon`, is nil.

Answer (score 0):

Did you remove the puts in the @rooms.detect {...} ?

Remove it, and it should work.

Comment: Actually, initially I did not have the puts in the @rooms.detect, I put it in there to see what that code was seeing. Same error even after I remove the puts there. Thanks!

Comment: @user688222 If you are trying to debug, you should use `p`, not `puts`, as that will give you more detailed information. And if you are using ruby1.9, having `p` in that position should not harm as its return value is its argument rather then constantly `nil`.